# Minimum number of Appends needed to make a string palindrome

Tags: c++

I tried doing this question using recursion in an interview.they said this solution is not efficient.How to make this code more efficient?

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
int palin(char str[], int len)
{
    static int cnt;
    int s = 0;
    int e = len - 1;
    while(s < e){
        if(str[s] != str[e]) {
            cnt++;
            return palin(str + 1, len - 1);
        }
        else{
            s++;
            e--;
        }
    }
    return cnt;
}

int main() {
    char str[100];
    cin.getline(str, 100);
    int len = strlen(str);
    cout << palin(str, len);
}
```

Comment: first improvement: `#include <cstring>` and use `strlen` instead of your `length` function.

Comment: [OT]: use `std::string` in C++ instead of char[100]...

Comment: Find the the LCS of the given string and its reverse. No. of insertions needed is `length(string) - length(LCS)`.

Comment: @jarod   sir,if i use string then how will i use str+1 in recursive statement

Comment: You still have `std::string::c_str()`, or you can pass whole string + indexes.

Comment: Your recursion needs to return a value, by doing that you can lead it to a memoization solution. This will help because you are solving several subproblems repeatedly. `(I+1,L-1) (I,L-1) (I+1,L)` where I use `I` and `L` and the left and right pointers to the string.

Comment: @SamerTufail Sir, am i solving sub-problems repeatedly? Plz explain

Comment: @AaravSingh you aren't then maybe you should, because the above cases need to be covered. Consider `abcda` what does your program return? 4 which is wrong the answer is 2. `dc` is the insertion.

Comment: @SamerTufail Sir,question is asking for appending characters ...it is not for insertion in the middle of the string

Comment: what do you append to `abcda` to make it palindrome?

Comment: @AaravSingh Are you also allowed to prepend?

Comment: for testcases like **abcdabc** i m going into recursion multiple times.i,e repetitive .how i can avoid that??

Comment: @jeffrycopps nope sir..

Comment: @jeffrycopps with the current code it would produce 4. Tells me otherwise.

Comment: I think you could do this using [Levenshtein Distance](https://people.cs.pitt.edu/~kirk/cs1501/Pruhs/Spring2006/assignments/editdistance/Levenshtein%20Distance.htm)